# How to make me Signout in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am creating a Login , Logout Page in flutter when i use Stream and Provider .  I get Some Errors.
Help me out of this
in the main.dart when i use the StreamProvider it says the intial data cannot be null, according to my Tutorial there is no intialdata and in auth.dart when i use the authStatchanges().map it gives me 'The argument type 'Userid Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Userid Function(User?)'

Error Places - auth change user stream & and StreamProvider in main.dart
Thanks

Auth.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:wasthu/Services/user.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

//create userobject based on firebase user
  Userid? _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? Userid(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

// auth change user stream
  Stream<Userid> get user {
    return _auth
        .authStateChanges()
        .map((User user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
  }

  //sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user!);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

 

  //signout
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:wasthu/Screens/Home/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:wasthu/Services/auth.dart';
import 'package:wasthu/Services/user.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<Userid>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: null,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

user.dart

```
class Userid {
  final String uid;
  Userid({required this.uid});
}
```

Comment: `_userFromFirebaseUser` returns a nullable type. Getter `user` is of a non-nullable type.

Comment: @Riwen I am begiiner to flutter can ypu explain me how to do it?

Comment: @Riwen made it bro thanks